# Show that there is at least one $a_n$ with $f_n(a_n)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

> Let $g$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ and $g([0,1])=[0,1]$, and let $f_n$ be a continuous function on $[0,1]$ defined by $f_n(x)=g(x)-x^n$. Show that there is at least one $a_n$ with $f_n(a_n)=0$.

I showed that $x\in[0,1]\implies f_n(x)\in[-1,1]$ **(?)** by using

$$0\leq g(x) \leq 1$$
 and 
$$-1\leq-x^n\leq0.$$
Thus 
$$\left|g(x)-x^n\right|\leq1.$$

Anyway this shows that $[-1,1]\subseteq f_n([0,1])$ **(?)**, thus $0\in f_n([0,1])$, hence there is at least one $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f_n(c)=0$, and all we have to do is to define the sequence $a_n=c$ for all $n$.

Is my proof correct?

**(?)** is where I have doubts

Comment: The fact that $|f_n(x)|\leq 1$ show that $f_n(x)\in [-1,+1]$ hence that $f_n([0,1])\subset [-1,1]$. Hint : compute $f_n(0)$ and $f_n(1)$.

Comment: @Kelenner $f_n(0)=g(0)$, and $f_n(1)=g(1)-1$. But I get to a problem, $0\leq g(0)\leq1$, and $-1\leq g(1)-1\leq0$, so there will be at least one $c$ in $[0,1]$ such that $f_n(c)=0$ That's it?!

Comment: Yes, you have done it.

Comment: @Kelenner there's no need to have $f_n(0)$ *sttrictly* positive and $f_n(1)$ *strictly* negative?

Comment: If $f_n(0)=0$, you can put $c=a_n=0$. The same if $f_n(1)=0$, put $c=a_n=1$.

Comment: @Kelenner i forgot to add that $g([0,1])=[0,1]$, so it would be a three case proof,?? anyway thank you so much! (:D) write an answer so that i accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that $|f_n(x)|\leq 1$ show that $f_n(x)\in [-1,+1]$ hence that $f_n([0,1])\subset [-1,1]$. Hint : compute $f_n(0)$ and $f_n(1)$.